# Resolve promise in object array before render it using express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, async-await

I've a mongoose schema in which a virtual property is defined:

```
mortSchema.virtual('count').get(function () {
    return Pickup.countDocuments({ mortician: this._id }).exec().then((count) => { console.log(count) })
})
```

I'm rendering it using express like this:

```
try {
  const morticians = await Mortician.find({})

  res.render('morticians', {
    title: 'Mortician',
    morticians: morticians
  })

  console.log(await morticians.count)
} catch (err) { /* err */ }
```

Since the promise it not solved at rendering time, it's outputting `Promise { <pending> }`, before the `then()` function to the console. How to solve the promise, before passing it to `res.render`? Where to insert the missing `await`?

---

**Workaround:** Removing the virtual property from the schema like this is **working**, but not answering my question:

```
try {
  const morticians = await Mortician.find({})

  for (mortician of morticians)
    await Pickup.countDocuments({ mortician: mortician._id },
      (err, count) => { mortician.count = count })

  res.render('morticians', {
    title: 'Mortician',
    morticians: morticians
  })
} catch (err) { /* err */ }
```

Comment: @ggorlen, vscode says "await has no effect on the type of this expression." and yes I tested it.